# .NET Google Sheets Api - At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-api, google-sheets

I'm trying to integrate Google Sheets in my web application. 
Basically I want to create a Google Sheet and insert some rows into it which I get from my DB Storage and then open the Google Sheet on the web client. I've tried the quick start indications on

https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites

I created a OAuth Consent, Got my Service account key and secret file and followed the steps but I keep getting:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Google.Apis.Auth.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set

Comment: assuming you are using the json file make sure its reading it.